# Using PyDev and Django in Eclipse and need to simulate a slow internet connection

Tags: django, eclipse, performance, connection, pydev

I'm trying to implement an ajax page loading icon, but of course I can't test it on my localhost because it loads instantly....

How can I simulate a slow internet connection with Eclipse Platform in Ubuntu which will allow me to test the loading icon???

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `time.sleep(5)` in your view before the return to sleep for five seconds.

Comment: OK, in the end I used this as a temporary and simple solution to do what I needed. However, using time.sleep didn't work - I did: `from time import sleep`, then `sleep(5)`. But thanks very much for getting me 90% of the way there!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use for middleware.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/1453629) is an example of middleware that delays every request by a certain amount, configurable in your settings:

```
"""
This module provides very simple Django middleware that sleeps on every request.

This is useful when you want to simulate slow response times (as might be
encountered, say, on a cell network).

To use, add this middleware, and add a value for SLEEP_TIME to your settings.

Possible future feature: Look for an X-Django-Sleep header on each request,
to let the client specify per-request sleep time.
"""

import time

import django.conf
import django.core.exceptions


class SleepMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sleep_time = getattr(django.conf.settings, "SLEEP_TIME", 0)
        if not isinstance(self.sleep_time, (int, float)) or self.sleep_time <= 0:
            raise django.core.exceptions.MiddlewareNotUsed

    def process_request(self, request):
        time.sleep(self.sleep_time)
```

You can get fancier from here, for example, with a randomness thrown in, this can be useful when testing complex ajax interactions.

Comment: This looks great, thanks very much! I'm not in a position to test now, but I'll do so soon and report back!

Answer (score 0):

For a delay of 200ms I simply use the following command:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp2s0 root netem delay 200ms
```

Change `add` with `del` to return at the original state.

You can monitor how things change making a ping on the delayed machine.

I took it from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/).